# Logical error in my function prevents count++ from working

Tags: javascript, function, count

I am struggling to find the last logical error in this code it still returns Found 0 wishes, rather than 12.

```
var msg = 'I wish to wish the WISH you wish to wish but if you wish '
+ 'the WISH the witches wish I won\'t wish the WISH you wish '
+ 'to wish';
document.writeln('Found ' + countTerms(msg) + ' wishes.');
function countTerms(phrase) {
var i = 1;
var count = 0 ;
var terms = phrase.split(' ');
    for (i = 0; i < terms.length - 1; i++){
        if (terms[i].toUpperCase() == 'WISH'){
return count++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `return` inside the for loop, for the very first match, we are returning count and then incrementing, which means function will return `0` there itself. And if there was no such match it will return `undefined` (default return).

You will need to return `count` after the for loop. Also, the condition in for loop has to be `i < terms.length` otherwise, we will miss the last value in the array.

```js
var msg = 'I wish to wish the WISH you wish to wish but if you wish '
+ 'the WISH the witches wish I won\'t wish the WISH you wish '
+ 'to wish';
document.writeln('Found ' + countTerms(msg) + ' wishes.');
function countTerms(phrase) {
  var i = 1;
  var count = 0 ;
  var terms = phrase.split(' ');
  for (i = 0; i < terms.length; i++) {
    if (terms[i].toUpperCase() == 'WISH'){
      count++;
    }
  }
  return count;
}
```

Please note, you can also simplify your code using [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). After splitting string into array, filter in only those values of array which have the value 'wish' and then return the length of the filtered array.

```js
var msg = 'I wish to wish the WISH you wish to wish but if you wish '
+ 'the WISH the witches wish I won\'t wish the WISH you wish '
+ 'to wish';
document.writeln('Found ' + countTerms(msg) + ' wishes.');
function countTerms(phrase) {
  return phrase.split(' ').filter(p => p.toUpperCase() === 'WISH').length;
}
```

Comment: Oh so simple, this code had 10+ logical and syntax errors in it and by the time I got to the last one I had looked at it for so long I couldn't see anything.

Comment: @will Also don't forget to remove the `- 1` from your `for` condition. You are skipping the last element now.

Comment: @Ivar - Very well noted! I have updated my answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

You always `return` the first `count` directly, which is 0 at that point. To keep counting, just do `count++` in the loop, and `return count;` after the loop is done.

Answer (score 0):

Don't return inside loop

```
for (i = 0; i < terms.length - 1; i++){
    if (terms[i].toUpperCase() == 'WISH'){
       count++;
    }
}

// Return hear
return count;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're returning a pre
-incremental value. This means that the variable is not updated until the return statement has finished running. to fix your code, change

```
return count++
```

to this

```
count++
```

and then return count at the bottom of the function, after the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

There are two mistakes. Return the count after the loop.
Another one is in the for loop:  you either use  i < terms.length or i <= terms.length -1; or else you will miss the last 'wish'

```js
var msg = 'I wish to wish the WISH you wish to wish but if you wish ' +
  'the WISH the witches wish I won\'t wish the WISH you wish ' +
  'to wish';
  
console.log('Found ' + countTerms(msg) + ' wishes.');

function countTerms(phrase) {
  var count = 0;
  var terms = phrase.split(' ');
  for (let i = 0; i < terms.length; i++) {
    if (terms[i].toUpperCase() === 'WISH') {
      count++;
    }
  }
  return count;
}
```